# Setting up SMTP to receive mail

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, smtp

Thanks to a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926345/pipe-incoming-email-to-a-script-on-windows-iis-smtp/929797#929797) on StackOverflow, I was keen to discover that I can set up SMTP in IIS6 to receive mail on my Windows 2008 server. However, I'm having a bit of difficulty as my test email results in a 'Delivery Status Notification - 5.3.5' error.

I've done some Googling and I understand this means a loop is present and that I should check my SMTP domains in IIS. I've apparently got to have 1 Local (Default) domain, which is currently set to my server name, and I've then added my domain (mail.mydomain.com) as 'Remote'. Is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. A remote domain is a domain that SMTP will send email to. A local domain is a domain that SMTP will recieve email for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you want is an Alias domain. An Alias domain is an alias for the local domain. Once you set up the Alias domain you can send email to a user at the Alias domain and SMTP will accept the email (presuming that the email gets there).